# os.environ doesn't show some variables

Tags: python, linux

I have an environment variable that I set (on Centos 6) using profile.d, as follows:

```
[bankap@tnt-integration-test ~]$ cat /etc/profile.d/tnt.sh
TNT_SERVER_URL=http://tnt-integration-test:8000/
```

and when I log in, I see the variable:

```
[bankap@tnt-integration-test ~]$ echo $TNT_SERVER_URL
http://tnt-integration-test:8000/
```

But when I access the thing with Python, the environment variable doesn't show up!

```
[bankap@tnt-integration-test ~]$ python -c 'import os;os.environ.get("TNT_SERVER_URL")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'TNT_SERVER_URL' is not defined
```

I've even tried using the ctypes library with the same results:

```
>>> os.getenv('TNT_SERVER_URL')
>>> from ctypes import CDLL, c_char_p
>>> getenv = CDLL('libc.so.6').getenv
>>> getenv('TNT_SERVER_URL')
0
>>>
```

But other variables come through just fine...

> > > os.environ
> > >          {'SSH_ASKPASS': '/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass', 'LESSOPEN': '|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s', 'SSH_CLIENT': '139.126.176.137 56535 22', 'SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE': '', 'LOGNAME': 'bankap', 'USER': 'bankap', 'QTDIR': '/usr/lib64/qt-3.3', 'PATH': '/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/bankap/bin',

Anybody have any ideas? I've never seen this before!

Comment: That NameError seems to indicate that you've got a quoting problem at least in your first example; `TNT_SERVER_URL` is being interpreted as a variable name instead of a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a quoting problem:

change

```
python -c 'import os;os.environ.get('TNT_SERVER_URL')'
```

into

```
python -c 'import os;os.environ.get("TNT_SERVER_URL")'
                                    ^              ^
```

You also (probably) need to `export` the variable:

```
export TNT_SERVER_URL; python -c 'import os;os.environ.get("TNT_SERVER_URL")'
```

Comment: You're right about the quoting, but that wasn't the problem:

    [bankap@tnt-integration-test ~]$ python
    Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 25 2011, 08:36:25)
    [GCC 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more   
    >>> import os
    >>> os.environ[
    ...
    KeyboardInterrupt
    >>> os.environ['TNT_SERVER_URL']
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError(key)
    KeyError: 'TNT_SERVER_URL'

Comment: Did you try exporting the variable? If you just type `export` before running Python, is the variable there?

Comment: you're right! That was the problem! Thank you. I guess I don't understand what 'export' is for. I thought that if you could echo a variable in the shell you should be able to get at it with os.environ

Comment: No, when you set a shell environment variable, it's by default only visible in that shell. It can't be seen by child processes, like Python in your case.  You have to export the variable in order to make it visible to child processes.  See this for more info: [export man page](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html)